# Outlook vsto failed to obtain the BodyHtml field of the mail object and a COMException occurred

Tags: outlook, vsto

There is an email in the mailbox and a COMException occurs when using the HTMLBody and Body in Outlook.MailItem,but can access the Subject field of the email.The message also says "If there's something wrong with the way this message is displayed, click here to view it in a web browser."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vuVE.png)

I expect to get the body field data of the email. I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

The error is as follows.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
HResult=0x8A404001 Message=未生效 Source=<无法计算异常源> StackTrace: <无法计算异常堆栈跟踪>

Comment: I have never seen that error code (0x8A404001). Does it only happen with a particular email?

Comment: I’m not very clear either. I only discovered this error when I received an email recently.